Submit not working in react hook form in editing
I have this component, component doesn't give any error but when I tried to submit my form onSubmit function is not triggered.
I used react-hook-form to create my form and I used shadcn UI components inside form. When I Click button which has type submit does not trigger onSubmit function which is called inside of handleSubmit. Why onSubmit is not triggered?
'use client';
import * as z from 'zod';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Trash } from 'lucide-react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import {
    Form,
    FormControl,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage
} from '@/components/ui/form';
import { Separator } from '@/components/ui/separator';
import { Heading } from '@/components/ui/heading';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
import { AlertModal } from '../modal/alert-modal';
import { Select, SelectContent, SelectItem, SelectTrigger, SelectValue } from '../ui/select';
import { Product } from '@prisma/client';
import { createDailyOrder, deleteDailyOrder } from '@/actions/daily-order-action';


const formSchema = z.object({
    date: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Date is required' }),
    dailyOrders: z.array(z.object({
        id: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Id is required' }),
        productId: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Product is required' }),
        quantity: z.coerce.number().min(1, { message: 'Quantity is required' }),
    }))
});

export type DailyOrderFormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

interface DailyOrderFormProps {
    initialData: any | null;
    products: Product[]
}

export const DailyOrderForm: React.FC<DailyOrderFormProps> = ({
    initialData,
    products
}) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const title = initialData ? 'Edit Daily Order' : 'Create Daily Order';
    const description = initialData ? 'Edit Daily Order' : 'Add a new Daily Order';
    const toastMessage = initialData ? 'DailyOrder updated.' : 'DailyOrder created.';
    const action = initialData ? 'Save changes' : 'Create';

    const defaultValues = initialData
        ? {
            date: initialData.date, dailyOrders: initialData.productsData
        }
        : {
            date: '', dailyOrders: [{ id: '1', productId: '', quantity: 0 }]
        }

    const form = useForm<DailyOrderFormValues>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues
    });
    const { fields, append, remove, } = useFieldArray({
        control: form.control,
        name: 'dailyOrders'
    })

    const onSubmit = async (data: DailyOrderFormValues) => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            await createDailyOrder(data, initialData);
            toast.success(toastMessage);
            router.push(`/daily-orders`);
        } catch (error: any) {
            toast.error(error.message);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const onDelete = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            router.refresh();
            await deleteDailyOrder(initialData.id);
            toast.success('DailyOrder deleted.');
            router.push(`/daily-orders`);
        } catch (error: any) {
            toast.error(error.message);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
            setOpen(false);
        }
    };


    return (
        <>
            <AlertModal
                isOpen={open}
                onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
                onConfirm={onDelete}
                loading={loading}
            />
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                <Heading title={title} description={description} />
                {initialData && (
                    <Button
                        disabled={loading}
                        variant="destructive"
                        size="sm"
                        onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
                    >
                        <Trash className="h-4 w-4" />
                    </Button>
                )}
            </div>
            <Separator />
            <Form {...form}>
                <form
                    onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                    className="w-full space-y-8"
                >
                    <div className="gap-8 md:grid md:grid-cols-5">
                        <FormField
                            control={form.control}
                            name="date"
                            render={({ field }) => (
                                <FormItem>
                                    <FormLabel>Date</FormLabel>
                                    <FormControl>
                                        <Input type="date" disabled={loading} {...field} />
                                    </FormControl>
                                    <FormMessage />
                                </FormItem>
                            )}
                        />
                        <Button
                            className='mt-8'
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => {
                                append({ id: `${fields.length + 1}`, productId: '', quantity: 0 });
                            }}
                        >Add
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {fields.map((item, index) => (
                            <div className='flex gap-4' key={item.id}>
                                <div className='min-w-60'>
                                    <FormField
                                        control={form.control}
                                        name={`dailyOrders.${index}.productId`}
                                        render={({ field }) => {
                                            return (
                                                <FormItem>
                                                    <FormLabel>Product</FormLabel>
                                                    <Select
                                                        disabled={loading}
                                                        onValueChange={field.onChange}
                                                        value={field.value}
                                                        defaultValue={field.value}
                                                    >
                                                        <FormControl>
                                                            <SelectTrigger>
                                                                <SelectValue
                                                                    defaultValue={field.value}
                                                                    placeholder="Select a product"
                                                                />
                                                            </SelectTrigger>
                                                        </FormControl>
                                                        <SelectContent>
                                                            {products.map((product) => (
                                                                <SelectItem key={product.id} value={product.id}>
                                                                    {product.name}
                                                                </SelectItem>
                                                            ))}
                                                        </SelectContent>
                                                    </Select>
                                                    <FormMessage />
                                                </FormItem>
                                            )
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <FormField
                                    control={form.control}
                                    name={`dailyOrders.${index}.quantity`}
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem>
                                            <FormLabel>Quantity</FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Input type="number" {...field} />
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />

                                <Button
                                    className='mt-8'
                                    variant={'destructive'}
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        if (index === 0) return;
                                        remove(index);
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <Trash className="h-4 w-4" />
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <Button onClick={() => { console.log(form.formState.errors) }} disabled={loading} className="ml-auto" type="submit">
                        {action}
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </Form >
        </>
    );
};


I tried to log the errors in the console and from form errors there are no logs but it works on adding new data with this form.

onSubmit won't trigger if you're missing form components that you specified in your formSchema. In your formSchema you specified dailyOrders as having 3  parts, but you only provided two FormFields. You're missing a FormField with name={`dailyOrders.${index}.quantity`}
